# Replacing PowerMock's @PrepareForTest programmatically?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermock

I am using PowerMock to mock static methods in junit tests, typically done as follows:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class,Bar.class})
public class SomeUnitTest {

  @Before
  public void setUpTest() {
    setUpFoo();
    setUpBar();
  }

  private void setUpFoo() {
    mockStatic(Foo.class);
    when(Foo.someStaticMethod()).thenReturn(1);
  }

  private void setUpBar() {
    mockStatic(Bar.class);
    when(Bar.someStaticMethod()).thenReturn(2);
  }

  @Test
  public void someTestCase() {
    ...
  }

}
```

This works fine, but I'm finding that specifying the `@PrepareForTest` annotation is preventing me from making my testing API flexible.

What I'd like to do is something like the following:

```java
public class MockLibraryOne {

  public static void setUpLibraryOne() {
    setUpFoo();
    setUpBar();
  }

  private static void setUpFoo() {
    mockStatic(Foo.class);
    when(Foo.someStaticMethod()).thenReturn(1);
  }

  private static void setUpBar() {
    mockStatic(Bar.class);
    when(Bar.someStaticMethod()).thenReturn(2);
  }

}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SomeUnitTest {

  @Before
  public void setUpTest() {
    MockLibraryOne.setUpLibraryOne();
  }

  @Test
  public void someTestCase() {
    ...
  }

}
```

Here my unit test has a dependency on `LibraryOne`, but it does not know which classes `LibraryOne` depends on, so it does not know which classes to add to the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.

I could make `SomeUnitTest` extend `MockLibraryOne` and add the `@PrepareForTest` annotation to the `MockLibraryOne` class, but I will have dependencies on more than just `MockLibraryOne` in other unit tests, so inheritance is not a general solution.

Is there some way of programmatically preparing a class for testing under PowerMock, instead of using the `@PrepareForTest` annotation? For example, something like the following:

```java
public class MockLibraryOne {

  public static void setUpLibraryOne() {
    setUpFoo();
    setUpBar();
  }

  private static void setUpFoo() {
    prepareForTest(Foo.class);
    mockStatic(Foo.class);
    when(Foo.someStaticMethod()).thenReturn(1);
  }

  private static void setUpBar() {
    prepareForTest(Bar.class);
    mockStatic(Bar.class);
    when(Bar.someStaticMethod()).thenReturn(2);
  }

}
```

I guess it would be nice if `PowerMockRunner` processed the `@PrepareForTest` annotation a little differently: for each specified class, it should not only add that class (and its hierarchy) to the list of classes to prepare for mocking, but then examine that class to see if it has any `@PrepareForTest` annotations as well:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MockLibraryOne.class})
public class SomeUnitTest {
  ...
}

@PrepareForTest({Foo.class,Bar.class})
public class MockLibraryOne {
  ...
}
```

}

So in this the `@PrepareForTest` annotation on `SomeUnitTest` would find `MockLibraryOne`, and the `@PrepareForTest` annotation there would drag in `Foo.class` and `Bar.class` as well.

So perhaps writing my own test runner to replace `PowerMockRunner` may be a solution.

Or perhaps there's a simpler solution, using `PowerMockAgent` class, for example?

edit: Mock Policies may be one solution: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPolicies

edit: Mock Policies works with `PowerMockRunner` but not (it seems) with `PowerMockRule` (which I sometimes require due to class loader issues).

Answer (score 1):

What you try to achieve will not work.

The problem is that powermock must rewrite the client class's code to intercept the static invocation and it can't do this after the class is loaded. Thus it can only prepare a class for test before it is loaded.

Let's assume you want to mock the `System.currentTimeMillis` invocation in the following simple class.

```
class SystemClock {
    public long getTime() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Powermock will not change the code of `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis`, because it can't. Instead it changes the `SystemClock`'s byte code so that it does not invoke `System.currentTimeMillis` anymore. Instead it invokes some other object that belong to powermock.

This is how powermock get's full control over the return value and allows you to write a test like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ SystemClock.class })
public class PowerMockitoTest {

    @Test
    public void systemTimeMillis() {
        SystemClock systemClock = new SystemClock();

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);

        PowerMockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(12345L);

        long time = systemClock.getTime();
        assertEquals(12345L, time);
    }
}
```

You can see that powermock has rewritten the client class in the stacktrace of your debugger. Set a breakpoint at `SystemClock.getTime` and step into the invoked method.

[image: Powermock stacktrace]

As you can see `SystemClock` invokes a `MockGateway`.

If you take a look at the variables on the stack of the `MockGateway` invocation, you can see how the original `System.currentTimeMillis` method is handled.

[image: debug variables]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for a [mock policy](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockPolicies)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I investigated `MockPolicy`, but as I noted above it only works with `PowerMockRunner` and not with `PowerMockRule`. I need to use `PowerMockRule` because of class loader issues, and the `MockPolicy` initializer only works with `MockClassLoader` provided by `PowerMockRunner`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you help this (taken from documentation)?

> You can also prepare whole packages for test by using wildcards:
>
> @PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames="com.mypackage.*")

So you can add the whole library to your prepare...

Answer (score -1):

Why do you even want to mock static methods? Why not wrap those static methods in a class that you can mock with mockito?

```
class FooWraper {
   void someMethod() {
     Foo.someStaticMethod()
   }
}
```

and then you can create a mock of your FooWraper. No need to use Powermock at all...

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and here's my motivation: Lombok generates static `builder` methods, and I'd like to test if all fields of a builder have been set (they are optional, so this is to prevent accidental omission when new parameters are added). To do this, I am mocking the static `builder` method to return a CGLIB proxy, with which I then count if all `set…` methods have been invoked. However, this adds four extra lines to each test: one for `@PrepareForTest` and another three for static block with `PowerMockAgentTestInitializer.initialize`. This question would solve my first issue.